# Hyper parameter tuning for multiple Outputs using mxnet in R

Tags: r, mxnet, hyperparameters

I currently try to build MLPs with multiple Outputs.

For single Output MLPs I normally use the H2o packge implementation which has a nice random grid search function implemented. Since H2o does not support multiple outputs I switched to the mxnet package.

Now I am trying to find a way to tune my parameters for my MLP. I can't find any package inside R which provides parameter tuning for multiple outputs and allows me to use mxnet.

Do you know any packages or do you have self implemented functions for a hyper parameter search?
Thank you!

*Edit in cause of comment:*

With multiple outputs i mean multiple response variables (MIMO problem). For example one of my researched tasks is the prediction of a RRSB distribution. A RRSB distribution has two parameters: n,x. I hope this clears your question

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean by multiple outputs?

Comment: I tried to be and updated my post. I hope this answers your question

Answer (score 1):

Have you consider Caret? I think it might do it as it provides both hyper-parameters tuning https://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html
and support some mxnet models, but unsure whether a MLP with multiple outputs is supported.

I personally use a grid or random search approach simply by sampling the required parameters from list of possible values associated to each. It involves looping over different hyper-parameter selection and keeping a log of each configuration performance.

Comment: I considered Caret. It is a good package but it doesn't support multiple outputs.
I think I will also have to use grid random search. I just would have preffered a package. But thx for the input

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](https://github.com/zackchase/mxnet-the-straight-dope/blob/master/chapter03_deep-neural-networks/mlp-dropout-gluon.ipynb) explains how you can build a Multi-Layer Perceptron using MXNet, in that particular case which has a Softmax layer as a final layer to classify the input as one of 10 different classes (MNIST problem).

In your case I believe what you want is a MLP with a final fully connected layer of 2 units, one for each variable you are trying to predict.
[Look here](https://github.com/zackchase/mxnet-the-straight-dope/blob/master/chapter02_supervised-learning/linear-regression-gluon.ipynb) for an example of linear regression. Your loss function would need to be adapted to your specific problem.